# There are "x" numbers of files (**.txt) that contain two specific characters, how can I select them?

Tags: java, arrays, file, search, filereader

Example:

String path: prod/java/company/mobile/reg/01

//Inside this file (/01) there are "x" number of files (**.txt) that contains two especific characters (a-z) how can i select them to read them?

Comment: what do you mean by _"//Inside this file (/01) there are "x" number of files"_?

Comment: Is **01** a `folder` or is it a `file` containing *file name* of other files in the format you specified?

Comment: We don't write your code. Show us what you have done